# Returning to first JQuery call after second

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here's the flow.

Input on page -> jquery call 1 -> sends data to first PHP page -> PHP pulls from DB and returns output -> revised input on newly loaded form -> jquery call 2 -> sends data to second PHP page that updates database with new record info

This is an update form - they enter their code, their info is loaded, they can update their info.  How can I then make it call back the first query if they want to make anymore changes?

Here's the JS file:

```
/* Primary Load Function  */
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $("#codesubmit").submit(function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $("#loding").css("display", "inline-block");
        $.post("codesubmit.php", {
                UniqueCode: $("#codeentry").val()
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $("#loding").hide();
                    $("#Success").slideDown("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#FullField").slideUp("slow");
                    }, 1500);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#FullField").html(data);
                    }, 2300);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#FullField").slideDown("slow");
                    }, 3500);

                    $("#codesubmit")[0].reset();
                }
                else {
                    $("#loding").hide();
                    $("#Error").slideDown("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#Error").slideUp("slow");
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });

    });
})(jQuery);
/* End Primary Load Function  */

/* Update RSVP Details Function */

(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $('body').on('submit','#updatersvpform', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $('#updatersvpform');
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        $("#updateloading").css("display", "inline-block");
        $.post("updatersvp.php", formData)
            .done(function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $("#updateloading").hide();
                    $("#UpdateSuccess").slideDown("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#FullField").slideUp("slow");
                    }, 1500);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#FullField").html(data);
                    }, 2300);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#FullField").slideDown("slow");
                    }, 3500);

                    $("#updatersvpform")[0].reset();
                }
                else {
                    $("#updateloading").hide();
                    $("#UpdateError").slideDown("slow");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#UpdateError").slideUp("slow");
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What do you mean "call back the first query if they want to make any more changes"?

Comment: Instead of using an anonymous function, you could declare it can call it again in the `done` callback of the second request

Comment: @DaveNewton - The first function responds to a form labelled codesubmit. The second function responds to a form labeled updatersvpform. Basically, I want the codesubmit function to process again so it reloads the update form for the end user to make any additional changes.

Comment: @HerrDerb I'm unfortunately a novice and not sure how to do that.  I appreciate your time already and will try to figure it out.